# Fixed navbar with bootstrap...?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

Here's an example: http://demo.18maret.com/demo/mimity/ the navbar it isn't staying in the top. I want that when you scroll, the navbar is fixed.

Comment: Please add a jsfiddle with your code. From Bootstrap: Add ``.navbar-fixed-top`` and include a ``.container`` or ``.container-fluid`` to center and pad navbar content.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a good jquery plugin for fixing the navbar on the top while scrolling down... : http://www.outyear.co.uk/smint/